# laravel catch all route making a css @import not work

Tags: php, laravel

I have a catch all route for my SPA

```php
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

This is working great however in my `app.css` I am doing,

```css
@import '/node_modules/modern-normalize/modern-normalize.css';
```

This, however, is for some reason hitting my catch all route, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: the request should only end up hitting your catch all if the path requested doesn't exist (isn't a file or folder) or isn't accessible, assuming the rewrite conditions were setup correctly to check for files and folders before handing off to `index.php`

Comment: Your `node_modules` folder is typically not in the `public` folder, and thus won't be accessible via the browser. This sort of thing is why asset compilation and SCSS is a default part of Laravel - they'll handle fetching the various `@import`ed assets for you. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix

Comment: Are you using Laravel Mix for that? What webserver you're using? NginX?